# Bazel rebuilds the project every new day

Tags: c++, linux, bazel

I have to use Bazel for a project on Linux. However, Bazel keeps rebuilding the whole dependency chain every new day I turn on my computer, which takes a lot of time.

I use the following command.

```
bazel run -c opt --action_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS='-std=c++17:-O3' some_target
```

In case it helps, I don't change the CXX or PATH environment variables every new day. I use oh-my-bash in my `.bashrc`

Here is the `--verbose_explanations` results:

```
Build options: --action_env='CCACHE_DISABLE=1' --cxxopt='-std=c++17' --host_cxxopt='-std=c++17' --incompatible_load_python_rules_from_bzl --compilation_mode=opt --force_pic --strip=never --strict_system_includes --config=release_debug --compilation_mode=opt --cxxopt='-std=c++17' --cxxopt=-O3 --cxxopt=-g --verbose_explanations --explain=a.log
Executing action 'BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt': unconditional execution is requested.
Executing action 'Creating runfiles tree bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/test.runfiles': Effective client environment has changed. Now using
  PATH=:/home/aminya/.vscode-server/bin/8908a9ca0f221f36507231afb39d2d8d1e182702/bin/remote-cli:...other_things...
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
```

I build the code inside WSL (using VSCode)

Comment: Dou you have disc cache enabled ? https://github.com/mgosk/bazel-scala-example/blob/master/.bazelrc#L1

Comment: No, I have not. Does that help?

Comment: Are actions actually being executed? When bazel starts up, it has to analyze the build to create the in-memory build graph (this is the "analysis phase" https://bazel.build/reference/glossary#analysis-phase). If you do a build, then do `bazel shutdown`, then do the same build again, is the behavior the same as what you're seeing on a new day?

Comment: If actions are being executed, you could try adding `--explain=<path>` and `--verbose_explanations`. That might give some information. See https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--explain

Comment: @ahumesky Thanks! I cannot reproduce the bug with `bazel shutdown`, but the logging flags are very helpful. I will report back the next time I face the issue.

Comment: @ahumesky I have added the log for the verbose explanations to the question

Comment: Great. So how many actions are rerunning? Is it all or most of the build? The log says "Effective client environment has changed", so I think you'll want to compare that log against another day's log to see what has changed.

Comment: I was able to debug the issue. The problem seems to be the PATH variable that changes. I had some path modifications in my `~/.profile`, which was not being sourced when I used the VsCode terminal. I have moved those to `~/.bashrc` to see if this gets rid of the issue

Comment: The `--incompatible_strict_action_env` switch can help make bazel independent of the environment in which you're running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution to this problem has been to be very careful with how I run Bazel. I strictly have a daily routine to open VsCode from GitHub Desktop and then use the inbuilt terminal of VsCode. Doing it in any other way (e.g. opening VsCode from the terminal) will cause rebuilds.

I also monitor the changes to `~/.bashrc`, which could trigger Bazel rebuilds.